# Is there a way to see when someone followed you on instagram through the API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My friend bought a bunch of followers for my instagram account as a prank, but I don't want a bunch of fake accounts following me. I was thinking of writing a script to remove all the people who followed me in the last 24 hours, but I don't see anywhere in the API where I might be able to see when someone followed me. Does anyone know if that's possible / know any other way I can get rid of the followers without manually blocking all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by

but this returns all the followers. Not only those which are followed you last. nor you get the date when they got added as followers in your list.

But I guess the list is sorted descending based on when they followed you in the response. So, latest followers should be on top in the response. Hopefully, that can help you.

Comment: "the list is sorted descending based on when they followed you" Are you sure of this? Because if that's the case then thats good since I know roughly how many followers I had beforehand.